# Get complete console history in R

Tags: r, console

How can I get the COMPLETE history of the console in R. I'm using Windows and RStudio?
I know the `history()` and `savehistory()` commands, but if I e.g. save my history with the `savehistory()` function, I only get a small part compared to what I can see when scrolling back through the history using simply the up-arrow key in the console. I also tried to use `Sys.setenv(R_HISTSIZE = 100000)`, but I don't get a longer output when using `savehistory()` afterwards.

Comment: `savehistory(); readLines(".Rhistory")`

Comment: @Rich Scriven Thanks for you answer but, I have no problem, reading the saved history file, but I need to go way further back in the history than I get using `savehistory(file="test.Rhistory")`. This is possible if I just use the arrow-up key in the console, but I need to have the code in the test.Rhistory file.

Comment: @lmo Thanks for the idea, but this did not work for me. `R_HISTFILE` sets the path and not the size.

Comment: when you say "COMPLETE", do you mean for the entire session? For the history of the project you're in? Or back to when you first installed RStudio?