# View entire session command history

Tags: r

I want to view a command I wrote early in a long-running R session. `history(Inf)` and `saveHistory()` only display 512 lines and I want to go back further. This information is *somewhere* since I can scroll back to the commands at the beginning of the session by holding the up arrow, but I don't know how to print all these commands to file. The only solution I have come up with is to select all text in the Bash window, save it and then grep for lines beginning with `>` or `+`. This is obviously ugly. Is there a better way to achieve this?

There is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46572193/get-complete-console-history-in-r) from five years ago asking the same question, but no solution was provided and I'm wondering if a solution has been developed since.

My R session is running in the Terminal on a Mac.

Comment: If you are using RStudio on Windows, you can find the history in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\RStudio\history_database`. It's a simple text file. If not, describe your setup.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm afraid I'm not using RStudio nor Windows. I am running an R session in Terminal on a Mac. Sorry for neglecting this detail in the question, I'll add it now.